# Why can't I find the image URL of the background on this site via inspect element?

Tags: html, background

http://conversionxl.com/dont-use-automatic-image-sliders-or-carousels-ignore-the-fad/

I'd like to figure out how they're handling their background but can't seem to find it in the source code anywhere. If anyone can direct me to how to find it, and/or knows how their background is set up and wants to just point me directly there, I'd appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
body {
    background: url("images/body-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #DADEE0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    font: 0.75em/150% "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",sans-serif;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

CSS which is using in http://conversionxl.com/dont-use-automatic-image-sliders-or-carousels-ignore-the-fad/

Answer (score 1):

```
body
{
    background: #dadee0 url(http://conversionxl.com/wp-content/themes/grido/images/body-bg.png);
}
```

It may look like just a white image, but click and drag after opening the image in a seperate tab and you'll see the pattern.